El método `reverse` no funciona en `cypress`
Quiero hacer el cy.log del array que recibe el testcase, pero al revés; parte del ejemplo lo tomé de la página de cypress:
it("Prueba de llamada a invoke", () => {
    const reverse = (s) => Cypress._.reverse(s);
    const double = (n) => n * n;
    const myArray = ["1", "2", "3"];

    cy.wrap([reverse, double])
        .invoke(0, myArray)
        .then((element) => {
            console.log(element);
        }); //Yielded ['1','2','3']
});


¿Tiene alguna relación esta pregunta con esta otra?

Y por cierto, en aquella pregunta fue revertida tu edición a una respuesta, ya que si estás queriendo agregar más detalles, debes agregar esto como edición a tu pregunta, no a la respuesta de otro usuario. Lo que sí podrías hacer es dejar un comentario temporal en la respuesta del otro usuario avisando que editaste tu pregunta.
